# Aborted connections when using node.js/mysql connectionPool

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var mysqlPool  = mysql.createPool({
  host    : 'localhost',
  user    : 'nodejs',
  password: '',
  database: 'nodejs'
});


// somewhere inside a method:
mysqlPool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    // do some queries

    connection.release();
});
```

I don't see any warnings in the output, but on the MySQL server I see **aborted connections** since testing with this node.js code.

**Do I have to close the connection pool when I stop the node.js app?**

If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're closing you're node.js app with a `Ctrl+C` command, you could close your connection pool on the [`SIGINT`](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_sigint) event:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  mysqlPool.end(function (err) {
    /* Since you're overriding the default behavior of SIGINT,
       you have to force your app to exit. You can pass it as 
       a callback to the end() function. */
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
```

But you could also configure your MySQL server to close idle connections, setting the server variables [`wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and/or [`interactive_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout).

It's up to you to decide what best fits your needs.

Comment: Yea, I close the app with CTRL+C. This solution sounds exactly like what I was looking for, can try it 2moz, thanks in advance!