# Server connection timed out when using mysql pooling

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io, connection-pooling

So I have been getting this error a lot recently.

```
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
at Protocol.end (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:$
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:1$
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

I have been searching a lot for a solution. I read a lot that mysql pooling would solve this, which I have been using for weeks now. The error still pops up though. Does anyone know why this could be?

I'm using this base function which I found in an answer on Stackoverflow. It handles all my queries

```
var mysql   = require("mysql");
var config = require('./db');
var db = config.database;

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 20,
    host: db.host,
    user: db.user,
    password: db.password,
    database: db.database
});


var DB = (function () {

    function _query(query, params, callback) {
        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                connection.release();
                callback(null, err);
                throw err;
            }

            connection.query(query, params, function (err, rows) {
                connection.release();
                if (!err) {
                    callback(rows);
                }
                else {
                    callback(null, err);
                }

            });

            connection.on('error', function (err) {
                connection.release();
                callback(null, err);
                throw err;
            });
        });
    };

    return {
        query: _query
    };
})();

module.exports = DB;
```

I'm executing queries like this:

```
    DB.query("SELECT * FROM lists WHERE list_id = ?", [listId], function (result, err) {
console.log(result);

}
```

Comment: I have had similiar problems with the connectionPool. Does [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912255/aborted-connections-when-using-node-js-mysql-connectionpool) help you?

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thank you for your reply, but I don't think it does. I keep the nodejs script running with pm2, so I don't close it with ctrl + c.

Comment: Do you have time between two queries? Because there is an idle timeout in mysql. If you don't query something for X seconds, the connection gets closed.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Yes, it is running persistent, so if no user connects it won't execute queries. But I thought mysql pooling would solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL Server has a variable called `interactive_timeout`, this means, if your connection is idle for X seconds, the server will close the connection.

You can increase this value slightly, but the prefered way is to acknowledge the timeout and simply use a new connection from the pool if you need to query something.

See https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#error-handling

The connection pool does not prevent any timouts, but the pool assures that you always have a connection, or have several connections if your application is under heavy load. If you only of very little traffic, you won't even need multiple connections, hence, you would not even need a connection pool.

Each connection in the pool will time out, because using `release()` does not close the connection but give it back to the pool.

So your disconnects are pretty normal and you should handle the error appropriately.

The connections are recreated automatically, see https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#poolcluster-options

```
canRetry (Default: true)
If true, PoolCluster will attempt to reconnect when connection fails.
```

**How do you correctly handle the error?**

Prepare a general error handler for all the MySQL errors:

```
// Above:
mySqlErrorHandler = function(error) {
    if (error.code == '') { // <---- Insert in '' the error code, you need to find out
        // Connection timeout, no further action (no throw)
    } else {
        // Oh, a different error, abort then
        throw error;
    }
}

// In the function:
connection.on('error', mySqlErrorHandler);
```

You need to find out `error.code` for your timeout. This can be done with `console.log(error.code);`.

Comment: Could you suggest any code which will recreate the existing connection(s) in the pool without the user having any issues? Thanks very much for the answer

Comment: The connections are recreated automatically.

Comment: So you are saying that if I just handle the error then my websocket won't crash because of the error and the pool will reconnect automatically? Or should I destroy the connection that timed out first?

Comment: If the connection times out, it is already destroyed and the pool will remove it automatically. You just have to fetch a new connection and retry your query. It's all in the documentation that I have linked in the answer :)

Comment: Then how can it be that I still get a time out error? I handle the error in the class I have provided in my question, so I don't see why I would get the error then.

Comment: @P.Yntema You handle the error, but you also throw it: `throw err;`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, will let you know if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @P.Yntema you're welcome! Let me know if you still have problems or if it works

Comment: @DanielW. there's one thing I'm not able to understand here. You mention fetching a new connection and retrying when it errors out but how do I do that? It fails all the time with a `ETIMEDOUT` error in `pool.query` even though I have `throw`. Please help. Stuck from a very long time on this and not sure how to proceed. The pool is failing on a single connection and is not retrying with a new connection.

Comment: @Ahkoy please ask a new question with your sourecode. The reconnecting itself should be done automatically.

Comment: @DanielW. thanks. it was just a connection issue between AWS ECS and AWS RDS. Fixed it by modifying security group.